# Do i need to create interface first in symfony2 before main class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to implement my own userBundle and i am am getting ideas from FOSUSerBunle.
WHile i see the code , i notice that he first created the UserInterface and then implements that interface on user entity.

I want to know that what is the use of userInterface , why can't i directly make UserClass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interface is an object oriented programming concept. In PHP, it declares (not defines) a set of public methods. Any class that implements an interface is required to define the methods declared within the interface. You can think of an interface as a contract.

Using interfaces allows you to '[program to an interface](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html)'.

In the case of FOSUserBundle, the `UserInterface` is meant to be used so that your user entity will actually work with the rest of the bundle. By agreeing to the contract of `UserInterface`, your user entity will contain the necessary methods that FOSUserBundle requires of it. Furthermore, you may see type hinting being used within FOSUserBundle that specifically refers to `UserInterface`, as opposed to a concrete user class.

If you're rolling your own user bundle, you don't need to implement any interfaces, as the design is completely up to you. But, it sounds like you're reinventing the wheel here, so I recommend just using FOSUserBundle.

Comment: The problem is i have the big application to develop and i am the new person. If i start building the replica of UserBundle then at least i will have the FOSUserbundle to check how they did it , so i learn from them.

Comment: But FOSUserBundle is *already* built - there's no sense in duplicating it. Life will be much easier if you use the tools that are available to you. Use FOSUserBundle and focus on writing the code specific to your application.

Answer (score 0):

So you can create you own user class that implements this interface. This way you can integrate your class with FOSUserBundle easily